# HP EX485 Media Server Keeps Powering Down & Restarting Automatically

Tags: hp-mediasmart

HP Home Media Server EX485 approx 3 years old.
Unit suddenly powers itself off and restarts automatically as if the power button was pressed.
Server restarts up OK for a few minutes and the cycle repeats itself again & again.
Reseated all drives, check fans in chassis and they are OK (turning).
Can login to server to see logs before it powers itself down again.

Suggestions any help is appreciated on resolving this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your power supply in your EX485 has gone bad!
Suggest you keep the unit power off to avoid damaging the data on your drive till
you get the PSU replaced.